# In PostGIS how can I do an ST_Intersection() search with a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Geography field?

Tags: postgis, intersection, geography-data-type, geometrycollection

I have a Postgres table "files" with a lat/lon location field of type `geography(GeometryCollection,4326)`. Right now the field only contains lat/lon polygons. I have succeeded in creating a gist index for the field and in doing a bounding box search with a search polygon:

```
select fileid, file_name, ST_AsText(location) 
from files 
where location && ST_MakeEnvelope (-81.0, 22.0, -76.0, 27.0);
```

But, I need to do a fully intersection search but I hit the restriction that `ST_Intersection()` does not accept a GeometryCollection. Maybe I could use `ST_Distance()` since I only need to know if a search area intersects a location area, not what the intersection area is. But I don't see any way to specify a spherical earth calculation, and that is probably all I need most of the time. I have been thinking about changing the field to a multipolygon since that would probably work.

It looks like `ST_Distance()` will work for what I need to do. It accepts a GeometryCollection and actually will do spherical earth calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ST_Dump` to explode your collection and use `ST_Intersects` against the resulting `SET`:

```
select
  fileid,
  file_name,
  st_astext(st_collect(a.geom))
from
  (
  select fileid, file_name, (st_dump(location)).geom as geom
  from files
  ) a
where ST_Intersects(geom::geometry, ST_MakeEnvelope (-81.0, 22.0, -76.0, 27.0, 4326))
group by fileid, file_name
```

Not sure if PostGIS will use an index on that query or if you can create an index for st_dump. You might need to evaluate with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Try using:

```
CREATE index idx_files_location_dump ON files USING gist((st_dump(location::geometry)).geom)
```